# Need help to set different different audio bitrate in multiple audio tracks using ffmpeg batch AV converter?

Tags: ffmpeg

i am using a "FFMPEG Batch AV converter" application on windows system, need help to set different different bit rate on each audio track? i have a file which have 1 video and 7 audio track (total 8).

Comment: May I point you at https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok please help with preset to achive.

Comment: @Rishikesh please take a look at the link above your comment. Look at a few questions asked on this forum to get an idea how questions should be asked here. Research more on ffmpeg. Look at the documentation and other examples. Post what command you are trying. And what is "FFMPEG Batch AV converter"? Your question is very unclear.